# How to find android apps occupies RAM memory space?

Tags: battery-life, ram

I wish to know about which app is occupies more memory space in RAM when i use multiple apps

Note: i just have RAM capacity of 256MB so that my battery downs soon.

Comment: The two items are not connected at all: Why should you save battery by estimating how much RAM an app uses? In order to "eat your battery", an app does not necessarily need a lot of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the following:

```
Menu - Settings - Apps - Running
```

And check out which apps are consuming more space in your Android Device.

Comment: how to find which app consume more battery power

Comment: @YellowFlash,
[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.carat.android&hl=en]

That link takes you to download Carat App.

Which claims to recommend you killing or stopping some apps.

It has a pretty good review.

Answer (score 0):

Though they are not necessarily linked, to find RAM usage:

```
Menu/App Drawer > Settings > Apps > Running
```

Some apps listed in this section might not be important but drain lot of battery over time.
Try to uninstall suspicious apps one at a time and figure out the effect on battery life. Find alternatives to apps which are eating up lot of resources, if possible.

You could also use an app (such as AVG Anti-Virus) to stay safe from malicious apps and have a control on various factors which could contribute to battery drain, such as GPS, Wi-Fi, screen brightness etc...